# Call in Batch Multiple Times

Tags: batch-file

I have a question with the "call" command in batch:

What if I have something like:
call Receive.bat hi

then later on in the code I have:
call Receive.bat gtg

And in Receive.bat I "echo" it.
Would it be like: echo &1 (for "hi")
                , Then later on: echo %2 (for "gtg")?

This is what I got:

```
@echo off
set /p Mood=:
call Receive.bat %Mood%
*Random stuff*
set /p Food=:
call receive.bat %Food%
```

Then in Receive.bat:

```
@echo off
echo %1 <-- for Mood
pause
*Random Stuff*
echo %2 <-- for Food
```

Comment: Ummm, NO. Receive.bat will run to completion for each CALL. Run some experiments and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: No one can answer a question with a single word, in this case: "No."

Comment: One more hint - `%1` gets a new value each time `receive.bat` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch files should do what you want if I have understood your requirements right.

**Main.bat**:

```
@echo off
set "CallCount=0"
set "Mood="
set /P "Mood=Your mood is: "
call Receive.bat "%Mood%"
rem *Random stuff*
set "Food="
set /P "Food=The food you want is: "
call Receive.bat "%Food%"
set "CallCount="
```

**Receive.bat**:

```
set /A CallCount+=1
if "CallCount"=="2" goto Call2
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem *Random Stuff*
goto :EOF
:Call2
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem Commands for second call.
```

Alternate **Receive.bat**:

```
set /A CallCount+=1
goto Call%CallCount%
:Call1
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem *Random Stuff*
goto :EOF
:Call2
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem Commands for second call.
goto :EOF
:Call3
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem Commands for third call.
goto :EOF
:Call4
if not "%~1"=="" echo %~1
rem Commands for fourth call.
goto :EOF
```

Comment: So what if I "call" more than multiple times? Like ten times? Would it be like: if "CallCount"=="2" goto Call2 if "CallCount"=="3" goto Call3, etc...?

Comment: And what does the "%~1" do in Receive.bat?

Comment: You have understood the system. For more than 2 calls, you need more labels for command __goto__. And a small modification as added to my answer. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` and you will see help of this command explaining also `%~1` which means string of first parameter without surrounding double quotes.